# Need help to fix my bash script

Tags: bash, certificates, certbot

I have create a bash script to renew security certificate for IKEve server. When I run the script it will ask me to press 2 and enter to renew the certificate. Can someone help me to add a command that can automatically press 2 and enter, then continue?

Here is below the bash output and my script.

```
What would you like to do?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: Keep the existing certificate for now
2: Renew & replace the cert (may be subject to CA rate limits)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 1
```

Here below is my bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
certbot certonly --rsa-key-size 4096 --standalone --agree-tos --no-eff-email --email xyz@hotmail.com -d mydomain.com
yes | rm /etc/strongswan/swanctl/x509/fullchain.pem
yes | rm /etc/strongswan/swanctl/private/privkey.pem
yes | rm /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/cacerts/chain.pem
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem /etc/strongswan/swanctl/x509/fullchain.pem
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem /etc/strongswan/swanctl/private/privkey.pem
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/chain.pem /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/cacerts/
exit
```

Comment: `yes | rm` would be better written as `rm -f`. Or use `rm -vf` if you want to see the names of the files you're deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `certbot -n`

```
-n, --non-interactive, --noninteractive
                    Run without ever asking for user input. This may
                    require additional command line flags; the client will
                    try to explain which ones are required if it finds one
                    missing (default: False)
```

You *might* also need `renew` instead of `certonly`(not sure).

---

Also, instead of `yes | rm`, you might want to use `rm -f` (`force` remove).